# Cant get Tabs to work in Python as i want them to

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to create a program which is navigated by a , lets call it, "Toolbar" at the top border of the program. I want to have there 5 Icons named with one word.

If you click the first Icon, it opens "Page 1" below the Icons, if i click the third Icon, i want it to open "Page 3" which have further functions like adding Customer data to a database, show all customers or something like that.

Now is the problem, how can i make this navigation.

```
   from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def doNothing():
    print("ok ok I won't ...")

root = Tk()
root.title("Project X")
root.geometry("400x300+200+100")


# *** Creating Dropdown on Top ***

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Settings", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=doNothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=doNothing)

# *** Creating Tabs ***

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack()

page1=ttk.Frame(nb)
page1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

nb.add(page1, text="Übersicht")
canvas = Canvas(page1, width=400, height=400)
nb.add(page1, text="Übersicht")
page2=ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page2, text="Kunden")
page3=ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page3, text="Katalog")
page4=ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page4, text="Layouts")
page5=ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page5, text="Hilfe")



# *** Status Bar ***

status = Label(root, text="Preparing to do nothing...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

If i do it like this, i am not able to get rid of the frameborders and i think / hope there is a more elegant way to solve this kind of problem.

With kind regards
Tim

Answer (score 0):

The borders of the notebook can be removed using a style:

```
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('noborder.TNotebook', borderwidth=0)
style.configure('noborder.TNotebook.Tab', borderwidth=0)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root, style='noborder.TNotebook')
```